# Error when a class inherites another class in a header file in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, header

//header file

```
#include <exception>
#ifndef CRYPTSERVEXCEPTION_H
#define CRYPTSERVEXCEPTION_H


class cryptServException
{
public:
//these are classes defined in a class 
class CantOpenForEncryption : public std::exception
{
public:

    const char* what();
};


class DecryptKeyMismatch : public std::exception
{

public :

const char* what();
};

#endif // CRYPTSERVEXCEPTION_H
```

there is this implicit constructor that is giving error I just can't understand the reason as we can leave the body of constructor empty, if there is some code to be place in it I don't know what it should, hope now you've got the problem.

//CPP file

```
#include "cryptServException.h"
//rest are just classes that are for exceptions
 cryptServException::cryptServException()
 {
 // this constructor declaration gives the error : definition of implicitly- declared 'constexpr myException::myException()'|
 }
//this is just a class in another class
cryptServException::CantOpenForEncryption : public exception
{

public :

const char* what()
{
    return " Can't Open File For Encryption ";
}
};

//this is just a class in another class
cryptServException::DecryptKeyMismatch : public exception
{

public :

const char* what()
{
    return " Incorrect Decryption Key ";
}
};
```

I can't determine the cause of error for the above mentioned implicit constructor.

thanks for help

Can you please suggest if I add a constructor in .cpp file what code should be placed in it's body

Comment: Where is the name `exception` defined?

Comment: actually I was directly using exception class of c++

Comment: But you didn't include the header that defines that class.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the `exception` token is not known to the compiler at the moment. It expects to see a class name at that point, however there is no class named `exception` declared above.

To fix it, add `#include <exception>` to your header file (if you mean `std::exception`, of course). Probably in your source file you have this file included indirectly.

Comment: thanks, this did work but the construct error still persists and also can you tell me why this didn't cause an error in .cpp file there I didn't include exception.h

Comment: @Nilesh Did you show the complete class which causes the error? This error shouldn't arise in this case.

Comment: what I have posted is just for show, actual code is a bit lengthy. But it is no different, the myException class contains 6 different classes for different types of exceptions.

Comment: @Nilesh "just for show" - you must post real code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: sure give me a few seconds

Comment: @NeilButterworth and IvanSmirnov check the post I've posted the actual code, and sorry for the worries

Answer (score 0):

the solution is

1. deleting the constructor declaration from cpp file, what I was doing wrong is that the constructor declaration was auto-generated stub and I ignored it.
2. also there's is no need to declare the class in .cpp file, just use full qualified name of method and implement it as suggested by @WhozCraig.

`const char *myException::CantOpen::what() const
{
    return "Can't Open File For Encryption";
}`

all of you were a great help

thanks